# pdo is not returning an output. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\webroot\wamp\www\index.php on line 12

Tags: pdo

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array (
'host'                      =>  'localhost',
'username'                  =>  'root',
'password'                  =>  '',
'dbname'                    =>  'pdologin'
);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['db']['host']};dbname={$config['db']['dbname']}",
      $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$query = $db->query("SELECT * 'firstname' FROM 'login'");
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['firstname'], '<br>';
 }
?>
```

When I run the code I get error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\webroot\wamp\www\index.php on line 12".

Whats making it error?  The only thing I can think of is the SQL query.

Comment: This is a dupe of about 2/3 of the entire Related sidebar.  Please do appropriate research and you will discover the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query has two syntax errors in it:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * 'firstname' FROM 'login'");
```

You can't use a string literal as a table in the FROM clause.

Explanation:  different types of quotes do different things in SQL.

- Single-quotes are always delimiters for string literals or date literals.
- In MySQL, back-ticks are delimiters for table identifiers (as well as columns and other metadata objects).
- Double-quotes are delimiters for table identifiers in standard SQL, and in MySQL if you set [SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html).  But by default in MySQL, double-quotes are the same as single-quotes, delimiting strings and dates.

You also had `'firstname'` in your query in an invalid place.  I can't tell if you meant that to name a column (if so, you were getting the quote type wrong again), or if you meant it to be a column alias (if so, you can't alias `*`, you can only alias a single specific column).

So your query should look like this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `login`");
```

Another mistake in your script is that you don't verify that `$query` is an object of type PDOStatement before calling PDOStatement methods on it.  PDO::query() will return `false` if there was an error in the SQL.  `false` is a primitive value, not an object, so it will naturally not have any methods you can call.  So you *always* have to check the return value before doing anything else with it.

For example:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `login`");
if ($query === false) {
  die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
}
```